# Convert yyyy-mm-dd to %m-%d pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column as below (it is not indexed) dates ranging from 2005 - 2015.

I want  to exclude the all the dates in 2015 and store in a dataframe. And on the filtered data I want to convert its format to `%m-%d` (i.e 2014-11-12 should be 11-12) and group all the data as %m-%d accordingly.

```
Date           Data_value
2014-11-12     12
2009-04-29     11
2008-05-26     -4
2005-11-11     18
2014-02-27     24
2010-10-01     0
2010-06-29     13
2005-10-04     34
2007-12-14     27
2011-04-21     -5
2013-01-16     9
```

Comment: Is the date column in a string format or is a datetime instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is kind of has multiple parts and it's missing a lot of info. Taking everything at face value, you need to make sure that your `Date` column is in fact a date-like type. From there you can easily compute a new columns with `df['Date'].dt.strftime()`, and then group on that column.

That looks like this:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas

datafile = StringIO("""\
Date           Data_value
2014-11-12     12
2009-04-29     11
2008-05-26     -4
2005-11-11     18
2014-02-27     24
2010-10-01     0
2010-06-29     13
2005-10-04     34
2007-12-14     27
2011-04-21     -5
2013-01-16     9
""")

excluded_year = 2013

print(
    pandas.read_table(datafile, sep='\s+', parse_dates=['Date'])
        .assign(year=lambda df: df['Date'].dt.year)
        .query("year != @excluded_year")
        .assign(month_day=lambda df: df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d'))
        .groupby(by=['month_day'])
        .sum()
        .reset_index()
)
   month_day  Data_value
0      02-27          24
1      04-21          -5
2      04-29          11
3      05-26          -4
4      06-29          13
5      10-01           0
6      10-04          34
7      11-11          18
8      11-12          12
9      12-14          27
```

Comment: @paul H - If the date column has 2015 year values, how to exclude them?

Comment: @SaiKrishnaChaitanyaChigili you don't have any 2015 data, in your example. Do you have it in real life (if so, you should include some when asking questions like this).

Comment: @SaiKrishnaChaitanyaChigili I edited the answer to demonstrate how to exclude a single year